# Why I cant' extract the field values of objects iterating on a JSON document using WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I am working on a **WSO2 ESB** project and I am finding the following difficulties:

I have a JSON document like this:

```
{
    "forecast_1": {
        "country": "Rwanda",
        "forecast_date": "2018-03-20",
        "province": "Kigali City",
        "district": "Kigali",
        "morning": {
            "min_temp": 14,
            "status": "Sun with right rain",
            "max_temp": 16,
            "humidity": "",
            "wind_direction": "",
            "wind_force": "",
            "description": "Lorem ipsum"
        },
        "afternoon": {
            "min_temp": 24,
            "status": "Dark cloud with rain",
            "max_temp": 28,
            "humidity": "",
            "wind_direction": "",
            "wind_force": "",
            "description": "Lorem ipsum"
        }
    },
    "forecast_2": {
        "country": "Rwanda",
        "forecast_date": "2018-03-25",
        "province": "Kigali",
        "district": "Kigali",
        "morning": {
            "min_temp": 21,
            "status": "Rain showers",
            "max_temp": 21,
            "humidity": "",
            "wind_direction": "",
            "wind_force": "",
            "description": "There will be heavy rain"
        },
        "afternoon": {
            "min_temp": 32,
            "status": "Rain showers",
            "max_temp": 32,
            "humidity": "",
            "wind_direction": "",
            "wind_force": "",
            "description": "There will be heavy rain with thunder"
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this JSON document doesn't contains an array of objects but contains some **forecast_XXX** objects, where **XXX** will change.

I have to iterate on each **forecast_XXX** objects (the first level objects) defined into this JSON document and extracts the values of the fields.

To iterate on these "first level" objects I am doing in this way (and it seems to work):

```
<foreach id="foreach_1" expression="//*[starts-with(name(), 'forecast_')]" xmlns:m0="http://services.samples">
    <sequence>
        <log description="Log" level="custom">
            <property name="iteration" value="ITERATION !!!"/>
        </log>

        <enrich>
            <source clone="true" xpath="/country/text()"/>
            <target property="test" type="property"/>
        </enrich>

        <log description="Log" level="custom">
            <property expression="$ctx:test" name="test"/>
        </log>

        <log level="full"/>
    </sequence>
</foreach>
```

The iteration seems to works because in my WSO2 logs I obtain:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-29 13:51:50,271]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  iteration = ITERATION !!! {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-29 13:51:50,271] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.elementary.EnrichMediator} -  Specified node by xpath cannot be found. {org.apache.synapse.mediators.elementary.EnrichMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-29 13:51:50,272]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  test =  {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-29 13:51:50,272]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: /meteo/forecast, MessageID: urn:uuid:21779fb7-6ce6-4e90-a9cb-4187dab8988b, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><forecast_date>2018-03-20</forecast_date></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-29 13:51:50,272]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  iteration = ITERATION !!! {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-29 13:51:50,272] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.elementary.EnrichMediator} -  Specified node by xpath cannot be found. {org.apache.synapse.mediators.elementary.EnrichMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-29 13:51:50,273]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  test =  {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

So, as you can see, I have 2 logs related to the current iteration, something lie this:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-29 13:51:50,271]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  iteration = ITERATION !!! {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

But now I am finding some difficulties to extract the field values related to the current object iteration.

I tried to do in this way:

```
<enrich>
    <source clone="true" xpath="/country/text()"/>
    <target property="test" type="property"/>
</enrich>

<log description="Log" level="custom">
    <property expression="$ctx:test" name="test"/>
</log>
```

but, as you can see in the log, the **enrich** mediato go into error and the **"test"** property will contain no value:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-29 13:51:50,271] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.elementary.EnrichMediator} -  Specified node by xpath cannot be found. {org.apache.synapse.mediators.elementary.EnrichMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-29 13:51:50,272]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  test =  {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

So what is wrong? Why the XPATH expression is wrong? How can I correctly extracts the field values of the current iteration object? (I am not so sure that using the **enrich** mediator is the best choice).

Answer (score 0):

Using xpath as follows worked for me.

```
//*/country
```

Here is the enrich mediator:

```
<enrich>
    <source clone="true" xpath="//*/country"/>
    <target property="test" type="property"/>
</enrich>
```

Result:

```
[2018-04-02 12:41:03,252] [EI-Core]  INFO - LogMediator iteration = ITERATION !!!
[2018-04-02 12:41:03,252] [EI-Core]  INFO - LogMediator test = Rwanda
```

Answer (score 0):

using //country/text() instead of /country/text() is working for me.